# How to stop a system.scheduler.schedule in Scala Akka

Tags: scala, akka, scheduler, actor, schedule

I currently have a method in place that creates a scheduler to send a message to my actors on set intervals. However, I am now trying to implement new functionality for a system shutdown.

I am able to stop the Actor in which these schedulers are created, but this does not stop the schedulers.

```
private def initialiseTask(taskName: String, taskActorRef: ActorRef, interval: FiniteDuration,
                             startDelay: FiniteDuration = 0 milliseconds, message: Any = "tick"): Unit = {
    logger.debug(s"Initialising task: $taskName")
    system.scheduler.schedule(startDelay,
      interval,
      taskActorRef,
      message)
    logger.debug(s"$taskName initialised")
  }
```

And as you can imagine, in the method is called for each actor I want to create a schedule for once this actor has started up. I have used schedulers before and cancelled them by assigning them to a val, and then using `.cancel()` on them, however, given this scheduler is used to schedule multiple things, I am unsure how I can cancel this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cancel a scheduled send, you need to save the `Cancellable` which the scheduler gives you when you call `schedule`.

Since you're scheduling in an actor, the logical place for this would be as part of the state of the actor: you can later send a message to the actor to tell it to cancel the scheduled sends.

A `Map` is probably the most suitable structure for storing the `Cancellable`s.  If you're not going to be reusing `taskName`, then it would make a fine key (i.e. you'd have a `Map[String, Cancellable]`), or maybe you might want to include `taskActorRef` or `message` as well.

How specifically one would do this depends on the style of actor definition (e.g. is it using the FSM DSL, or `context.become`, or tracking state via `var`s?).